# Which Omron Blood Pressure monitors are compatible with Samsung Health

Tags: measurement-devices

- A few years ago, the only BP device that would work with Samsung Health was obsolete and could not be purchased.
- After buying 3 of them I found one that was compatible with Omron App in NZ.  For some reason different models work in different countries.
- A few updates later, Samsung Health and Omron were co-operating and migrating the readings from Omron to Samsung Health automatically.
- A few updates ago, this stopped working.  Support for both organisations do not understand the problem.

So, I am in the market for a Blood Pressure monitor that will work with Samsung Health.  I cant seem to find the compatible models in the app anymore.

What model(s) of Omron devices will work directly with Samsung Health?